# Multiline Text Highlight go all the way to the end of the div instead of the end of the text

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a highlight that works like my top image, but can only get it to look like them bottom one. How can I achieve the look of the top one with basic or tailwind css?

Edit: Naturally breaking text and ideally also highlighted like this when a user selects it, but the main use case is for highlighting a section of a document to a user before they do something.

[image: Two Versions of a Highlight I am proposing]

Comment: For naturally breaking text, I don't see any easy way to achieve this. If you are in control of how the text breaks, you could add non-breaking spaces to "fill up" those lines, and then using the `::selection` pseudo class would work.

Comment: Are you talking about highlighting when the user selects a portion of text or is something else causing the highlighting?